# Liquibase creating index for Oracle fails

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I'm trying to create an index with Liquibase

Here is the changeSet

```
<changeSet id="....
    <createIndex tableName="xyz"    indexName="abc">
        <column name="column1"/>
    </createIndex>
```

But I'm getting this error

Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE INDEX .abc ON xyz(column1): ORA-00953: missing or invalid index name

Note: The same liquibase file is processed with PostgreSQL on development and with H2 for unit tests. It's working fine for those databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index name cannot start with .

Comment: isn't the index called "abc"?

Comment: No when you specify a . as the first character the following format is expected <schema-name>.<object-name>. This is not the case here.